# Actionscript 2.0 Movie clip

Tags: flash, actionscript

I am using an ActionScript 2.0 for my project. I have a movie clip named ant_mc. My problem is, the movie clip "ant" is just hidden and its not totally disappeared or remove. this is my code to hide the movie clip.

```
var keyListener:Object = new Object();
keyListener.onKeyDown = function() {

if (textbox.text == "ant"){
ant_mc._visible = false;

}
```

i want ant_mc to disappear permanently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create the movie clip with ActionScript, just call the `removeMovieClip` method.

```
ant_mc.removeMovieClip();
```

However, if you create the movie clip in the editor, then you will need to use the `swapDepths` method first.

```
ant_mc.swapDepths(0);
ant_mc.removeMovieClip();
```